# Facebook's JS API behaves differently in hidden tab

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, browser

On my website, I check if the current user already likes its fan page. If not, I display a pink arrow as a hint.

This seems to work correctly when opening the page and waiting for everything to be loaded. However, if I just type in the address, press enter and instantly switch to another browser tab, I can come back later to find the pink arrow, even though I already like the fan page.

The method for detection is the following (called on `$(document).ready()`):

```
function showLikeHint() {
    if (typeof FB === 'undefined') {
        setTimeout(showLikeHint, 100);
        return;
    }

    FB.api('/me/likes/339255156110755', {limit: 1}, function(r) {
        try {
            if (FB.getUserID() != "" && r.data.length == 1)
                iLikeFanpage();
            else
                iDontLikeFanpage();
        } catch (e) {
            setTimeout(showLikeHint, 200);
        }
    });
}
```

Is it possible that the api (i.e. the `FB` object) behaves differently when running in a hidden tab? I cannot believe that, but I have no idea what else could be the cause...

The problem occurs on http://lolkitten.org/ and could be reproduced with the latest chrome.

Comment: can you add the code around this call? do you run it within window.fbAsyncInit? do you wait for the window.fbAsyncInit to finish?

Comment: Done. I didn't know how to register for the event of finished initialization... Btw, the init is done elsewhere, I was just trying to avoid re-initialization...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem. If the user is not authenticated yet, `r.data` will be `undefined`. My solution to that is the following:

```
FB.getLoginStatus(function (loginResponse) {
    if (loginResponse.status !== 'connected') {
        iDontLikeFanpage();
        return;
    }

    FB.api('/me/likes/339255156110755', {limit: 1}, function(r) {
        try {
            var likeData = r.data;
            if (typeof likeData === 'undefined') {
                setTimeout(showLikeHint, 200);
                return;
            }

            if (FB.getUserID() != "" && likeData.length == 1)
                iLikeFanpage();
            else
                iDontLikeFanpage();
        } catch (e) {
            setTimeout(showLikeHint, 200);
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This does not matter which tab is visible in the brwoser view port, you should place the function `showLikeHint` inside a `$(window).load`, thets what i would do, `$(document).ready()` gets called when the HTML Document is loaded and the DOM is ready, `$(window).load` gets called when complete page is fully loaded, including all frames, objects and images, hope this helps you.

Comment: I actually tried this before. However, I would not work. The callback function was never reached, switching to `$(document).load()` or `$(body).load()` did not help either...